# Can a contact be matched with a campaign

Tags: contacts, civicampaign

Is it possible to match individuals with campaigns?

Example: I create an event, can assign contacts to this event with a role.
So I have the overview which contacts have participated.

Is it also possible to assign contacts to a campaign? So that I can see who participated and what role he had?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't completely clear to me. You can associate one person, or a few, with a campaign by creating a custom contact reference field for them.

You could also search for individuals who have been involved in a campaign in some way, e.g., donating to it, from Search > Advanced Search. You could then make a smart group from the results.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

In Civi there is campaign and event. Donation can only be mached with campaign, not with events? And contacts can only mached with events?

Example: I creat an event, can assign contacts to this event with a role.
So I have the overview which contacts have participated.

Is it also possible to assign contacts to a campaign? So that I can see who participated and what role he had?

I hope this is more clear. Thanks.